# Is there a shorter version of how you use MethodInvokingFactoryBean in cfg file?

Tags: spring

Currently it is used as shown below...wondering if there is a shorter version (similar to the util namespace)

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject">
            <ref bean="transformation" />
        </property>
        <property name="targetMethod">
            <value>addTransformers</value>
        </property>
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <ref bean="customTransformers" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it a bit shorter by using Spring [P-Namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-p-namespace)

Answer (score 2):

You're using very verbose syntax, you can make it shorter just by being more concise:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="transformation"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addTransformers"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="customTransformers" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Aside from that, and maybe using the `p:` syntax mentioned by @Ralph, I'm not aware of a namespace-based shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using @Configuration but for setting a System property, you can adapt though:

```
@Bean
public Properties retrieveSystemProperties(){
    return System.getProperties();
}

private Properties systemProperties;
public Properties getSystemProperties() {
    return systemProperties;
}
@Resource(name="retrieveSystemProperties")
public void setSystemProperties(Properties systemProperties) {
    this.systemProperties = systemProperties;
}

@Bean 
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() { 
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setStaticMethod("java.lang.System.setProperties"); 
    systemProperties.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(new Object[]{systemProperties}); 
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any parameters, you can do this:

```
<bean id="mybean" factory-instance="otherBean" factory-method="getMyBean"/>
```